# When compare count and element value does not work?

Tags: protractor

This is my code:

```
element.all(by.repeater("el in leaveApproved | orderBy:'Applied_Date' track by $index"))
  .count()
  .then(function(str){
     element(by.linkText('Dashboard')).click();
     browser.sleep(500);
     expect(element(by.xpath(
            "//*[@id='divDashboardAppCtl']/div[2]/div[2]/div[1]/div/div[2]/h1"))
       .getText()).toBe(str);
});
```

When I run, I got Failures:
login page Should check the count for Request Pending leave
  Message:

> [31m    Expected '37' to be 37.[0m   Stack:
>       Error: Failed expectation
>           at E:\Selenium\Users\Rafeeq\Proc_wfm\spec.js:119:108
>           at ManagedPromise.invokeCallback_ (E:\Selenium\Users\Rafeeq\Proc_wfm\node_modules\selenium-webdriver\lib\promise.js:1376:14)
>           at TaskQueue.execute_ (E:\Selenium\Users\Rafeeq\Proc_wfm\node_modules\selenium-webdriver\lib\promise.js:3084:14)
>           at TaskQueue.executeNext_ (E:\Selenium\Users\Rafeeq\Proc_wfm\node_modules\selenium-webdriver\lib\promise.js:3067:27)
>           at asyncRun (E:\Selenium\Users\Rafeeq\Proc_wfm\node_modules\selenium-webdriver\lib\promise.js:2927:27)
>           at E:\Selenium\Users\Rafeeq\Proc_wfm\node_modules\selenium-webdriver\lib\promise.js:668:7
>           at process._tickCallback (internal/process/next_tick.js:68:7)

Comment: make `.toBe(`'37'`);` you are getting the value with `'` surrounded.

Answer (score 0):

`element.all().count()` return a `Number`, but `getText()` return a `String`.

`expect().toBe()` will compare both the Type and Value of the data, equivalent to `===`

You need to convert the number to string.

```
expect(element(by.xpath(
            "//*[@id='divDashboardAppCtl']/div[2]/div[2]/div[1]/div/div[2]/h1"))
       .getText()).toBe(str+'');
```